# Create a Unix alias with $(...) does not work

Tags: bash, unix, alias

I have the following, working Unix command:

```
docker container stop $(docker container ls -a | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}')
```

I would like to assign this to an alias, like `sc` (stop containers) but this command does NOT work:

```
alias sc="docker container stop $(docker container ls -a | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}')"
```

It seems that the expression is evaluating somehow while adding it to the alias instead of just assign it.

How can I make it work?

**--- UPDATE ---**

This command also works fine as a command:

```
docker container ls -a | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' | xargs docker container stop
```

Result:

```
49b947bb6d61
cb25909f1d58
99bd5a3690c8
147f554934c8
```

But if I assign it to alias does not work:

```
alias sc="docker container ls -a | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' | xargs docker container stop"
```

Result:

```
49b947bb6d61
weblogic-admin-server
cb25909f1d58
oracle-db
99bd5a3690c8
weblogic-managed-server-1
147f554934c8
weblogic-managed-server-2
Error response from daemon: No such container: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Error response from daemon: No such container: bin/sh -c '$ORACLE…
Error response from daemon: No such container: 46
Error response from daemon: No such container: hours
Error response from daemon: No such container: ago
Error response from daemon: No such container: Exited
Error response from daemon: No such container: (137)
Error response from daemon: No such container: 45
Error response from daemon: No such container: hours
Error response from daemon: No such container: ago
```

Comment: `alias sc="docker container ls -a | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' | xargs docker container stop"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this also does not work as an alias. Your command works but if I assign it to an alias then not.

Comment: IMO, the correct way to this is to use `docker containter ls -a -q` instead of filtering with awk.  By avoiding the awk, you can use single quotes easily to define the alias.  (This should be a function, not an alias, but that's a different discussion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really ought to use a function:

```
sc() { docker container stop $(docker container ls -a | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}'); }
```

But you could also simplify the construction of the alias by getting rid of the awk:

```
alias sc='docker container stop $(docker container ls -a -q)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `$` in your `.bashrc` file

Try this:

```
alias sc="docker container stop \$(docker container ls -a | awk 'NR>1 {print \$1}')"
```

or

```
alias sc="docker container stop \$(docker container ls -aq)"
```